# Communication with API

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Here I converted a JSON to a map and a list of strings.
I also created the data model,
but I don't get any response and I get an error.

*When I clear the JSON mapping part and only read a value from the response, it is ok and works.*

There is a problem with mapping that no matter what I do, it doesn't work.
The data type is also dynamic, but it writes this error in the debug console.
If anyone knows, I would appreciate it if you could help me.

**- Code:**

```
Future<void> getDada(context) async {
  var response = await Dio().get('*****');

  List<MovieLists> moviesList = response.data['data']
      .map<MovieLists>((jsonMapObject) => MovieLists.fromMapJson(jsonMapObject))
      .toList();
  print('---------------> ${moviesList.length}');
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => homeScreen(listMovies: moviesList),
    ),
  );
}
```

**debugConsole Error:**

```
E/flutter ( 4602): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
E/flutter ( 4602): #0      new MovieLists.fromMapJson (package:movie_app_1/data/models/movies_list_model.dart:29:20)
E/flutter ( 4602): #1      getDada.<anonymous closure> (package:movie_app_1/screens/splashScreen.dart:44:54)
E/flutter ( 4602): #2      MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:415:31)
E/flutter ( 4602): #3      ListIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:344:26)
E/flutter ( 4602): #4      new _GrowableList._ofEfficientLengthIterable (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:189:2
```

**MovieLists Class:**

```
class MovieLists {
  int id;
  String title;
  String poster;
  String year;
  String country;
  String imdbRating;
  String genres;
  String images;

  MovieLists(
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.poster,
    this.year,
    this.country,
    this.imdbRating,
    this.genres,
    this.images,
  );
  factory MovieLists.fromMapJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonMapObject) {
    return MovieLists(
      jsonMapObject['id'],
      jsonMapObject['title'],
      jsonMapObject['poster'],
      jsonMapObject['year'],
      jsonMapObject['country'],
      jsonMapObject['imdb_rating'],
      jsonMapObject['genres'],
      jsonMapObject['images'],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code from your `MovieLists` class? The error seems to appear in line 29

Comment: @AppSolves - It was placed

Comment: It seems like your `genres` is a list, not a string. You have to change the type